# Error while importing Flet package in Python

Tags: python, flutter, user-interface

i've uncommon error while im just importing package **flet** to my code. I tripple checked installation of the package - all seems to be good, name of the file where im doing it is also other than flet/flutter/gui. All i can provide is error log:

```
File "p:\blahblah\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import flet
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\flet\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flet import (
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\flet\audio.py", line 7, in <module>
    from beartype import beartype
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\beartype\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from beartype._decor.decormain import beartype
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\beartype\_decor\decormain.py", line 24, in <module> 
    from beartype._data.datatyping import (
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\beartype\_data\datatyping.py", line 129, in <module>
    BeartypeReturn = Union[BeartypeableT, BeartypeConfedDecorator]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 243, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 316, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem(self, parameters)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 421, in Union
    parameters = _remove_dups_flatten(parameters)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 215, in _remove_dups_flatten
    all_params = set(params)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I also tried with venv (i thought its some package issue) but it doesnt help. Looking forward to your help!

Comment: The problem does not occur in a new Python 3.10 environment on Windows. What OS are you on, what version of Python? Have you tried installing `flet` in a new virtual environment, to make sure the problem isn't some unexpected interaction with something else you have installed?

Comment: okey, update to latest version of python helped me in this case! Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm using python 3.10